# 12 VDC motor stops after 1 or 1/2 turns

Tags: motor, dc

I have a 12 VDC motor for a water pump which is for a water dispenser of the bottom-loading type. Basically it's a diaphragm type pump.

When I connect it, it rotates once, then stops. When I remove the load, it is still the same: one rotation, then it stops.

Electric supply is for motor
Set for not continues but there is a pulse.

It should rotate intermittently to operate the pump.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the power supply activates overcurent protection.  Some PSs shut off output when overloading. Brushed motor has start current bigger a few times of working current. You may use PS with restricted output current but it should provide enough power  for start.